# Wordpress Editing - Cannot Find Footer & Custom Box

Tags: wordpress, footer

I have been asked to edit a wordpress website. I am not at all familiar with WP but have worked through the editor and made most of the changes requested. I cannot change the footer text. There are no footer pages. When I search for the footer text in the pages from the edit menu e.g. London, nothing comes up. I have inspected the elements in chrome and the attributes I need to edit are :

```
footer-cols  col one_third last
custom-box-content
```

[image: Footer?]

Comment: Do you mind giving me the website so I can take a look at it?

Comment: @KRUKUSA http://elixireducation.com see image above

Comment: footer.php in the active theme folder or parent theme folder usually or it may be a widget area

Comment: @David The footer.php script doesn't have any of the footer text. It's located in this dir :

wp-content/themes/limitless

Comment: yes but it has the code that creates the header, remember wp is mostly database driven so check your widgets area under appearance in the admin section, it may be there. It could be that the author used a function to output, etc...theres no way for me to know from a picture and some html output. But dig yourself, you have the starting point which is footer.php

Comment: @MBM it should be in the footer.php which you can locate in your theme.

Comment: I found the settings in widgets. Thank you.